# How to identify and homogenize date format of instances in a string?

Tags: string, matlab, date, format

I can't find a way to identify the date formats of a string in MATLAB and put all of them in the same format. I have the following cell array:

```
list = {'01-Sep-1882'; ...
        '01-Aug-1895'; ...
        '04/01/1912'; ...
        'Tue, 05/28/46'; ...
        'Tue, 03/10/53'; ... 
        '06/20/58'; ...
        'Thu, 09/20/73'; ...
        'Fri, 08/15/75'; ...
        'Sun, 12/01/1996'};
```

If I do `datenum(list)` there's an error message because all the rows don't have the same date format. Can you think of a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Is `list` a cell array?

Comment: Hi @rayryeng, yes, it is. The format is: list = '12/15/68'    'Sun, 01/15/89'...

Comment: One way to do this would be to loop through each element of the cell and use `datenum` on those individually.   However, if you use `datenum` on any elements in your cell array that begin with the day of the month in alphabetic form: `Tue, Thu, Fri`, etc. followed by numeric form of the date, MATLAB currently has no built-in format specifier to look for this kind of date so it will give you an error here.  Is it safe to discard these and just rely on the numeric form of the date?

Comment: Going along with @rayryeng, the simplest (and likely least elegant) solution may be to simply loop over the cell array and store the individual datenums to a new numList. This should leave numList as a nice homogeneous numeric array to process as you please.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by successively applying [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) to convert each format and [`isnat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnat.html) to identify those dates that didn't convert properly. In addition, you can specify days of the week in the [date format string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime-properties.html#property_d0e189746) and what [pivot year](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#input_argument_d0e188957) to use for years with only the last two numbers. Starting with the sample data and expected date formats in your question, here's the code to do it:

```
% Input:
list = {'01-Sep-1882'; ...
        '01-Aug-1895'; ...
        '04/01/1912'; ...
        'Tue, 05/28/46'; ...
        'Tue, 03/10/53'; ...
        '06/20/58'; ...
        'Thu, 09/20/73'; ...
        'Fri, 08/15/75'; ...
        'Sun, 12/01/1996'};

% Conversion code:
dt = datetime(list, 'Format', 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
index = isnat(dt);
dt(index) = datetime(list(index), 'Format', 'MM/dd/yy', 'PivotYear', 1900);
index = isnat(dt);
dt(index) = datetime(list(index), 'Format', 'eee, MM/dd/yy', 'PivotYear', 1900)

% Output:
dt = 

  9×1 datetime array

   01-Sep-1882
   01-Aug-1895
   01-Apr-1912
   28-May-1946
   10-Mar-1953
   20-Jun-1958
   20-Sep-1973
   15-Aug-1975
   01-Dec-1996
```

Now you can convert these to numeric values with [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html):

```
dnum = datenum(dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue here is that MATLAB's `datenum` cannot understand this format: `Tue, 05/28/46`. So let's clean the original list so that it can understand.

```
% original list
list = {'01-Sep-1882','01-Aug-1895','04/01/1912','Tue, 05/28/46','Tue, 03/10/53','06/20/58','Thu, 09/20/73','Fri, 08/15/75','Sun, 12/01/1996'}

% split each cell in the list
list_split = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,' '), list, 'UniformOutput', false);

% now detect where there is unusual format, this will give logical array
abnormal_idx = cellfun(@(x) length(x) == 2, list_split,'UniformOutput', true)

% make copy
clean_list = list;

% now at abnormal indices retain only the part that MATLAB understands
clean_list(abnormal_idx) = cellfun(@(x) x{2}, list_split(abnormal_idx), 'UniformOutput', false);

% now run datenum on clean list
date_num = cellfun(@datenum, clean_list, 'UniformOutput', true);
```